# Making two rowed divs with HTML/CSS

Tags: html, css

I have this html:

```
<div class = "boxes">BOX1</div>
<div class = "boxes">BOX2</div>
<div class = "boxes">BOX3</div>
<div class = "boxes">BOX4</div>
```

and I want them to look like

```
BOX1  BOX2
BOX3  BOX4
```

The problem is, each boxes have different heights. So, say when `box1` is longer, I want the box just below it (in this case `box 3`) to move down just so that `box1` can fit (I don't want it to move down to the third row, I want it just below `box1`):

```
BOX1  BOX2
      BOX4
BOX3
```

I should tell you that I only have access to the class, and I cannot `css` of each individual boxes.

Answer (score 1):

set min-height to something to all boxes

like

```
 .boxes{
 min-height:100px;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class=" wrapper ">
    <div class = "boxes">BOX1</div>
    <div class = "boxes">BOX3</div>
</div> 
<div class=" wrapper " >
    <div class = "boxes">BOX2</div>
    <div class = "boxes">BOX4</div>
</div>
```

maybe you should do it like this